# blazor token refresh stale cookie problem

Tags: cookies, token, refresh, blazor

I am trying to implement [Jon McGuire's excellent OpenID  API Token Refresh solution and he left the last part to update the cookie](https://mcguirev10.com/2019/12/17/blazor-openid-connect-api-token-refresh.html#stale-cookies) as a tease. His suggestion is to set up a controller which will give access to the HttpContext and then use

```
var cookieAuth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");
cookieAuth.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", cookieAuth.Principal, cookieAuth.Properties);
```

I'm able to do that however the cookieAuth that I get is not valid and has null cookieAuth.Properties and cookieAuth.Principal. I've spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to solve this however everything I have tried has failed. As Jon points out in his article there are major gaps in the Blazor solutions and documentation offered and this is surely one of them. He also points out the abundance of well meaning yet incorrect or out of date solutions and advise out there. In that light I'm looking for a proven and durable solution to this issue that stays within the Blazor framework. I've already spent too much time on dozens of try this or try that approaches.
TIA

Comment: any success on finding a solution?

Comment: Amazingly no. It seems to me this is a fundamental need, yet ... crickets.

Comment: Seems like implementing server side session handling with persistence might be the best way around this, where the cookie is only used to store basic info such as name, subject and and session id and the server holds tokens, state, etc.